# How to first examine the input before proceed the program? or shouldn't I? why?

Tags: c, logical-operators

So today I am learning the "while" loop in c#,
the task was simple:

you can keep input score between 0~100;
when you in put "-1", the program ends;
it'll output the sum and the average.

here is our teacher's answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int score = 0; 
    int sum = 0; 
    int count = 0; 
 while(score != -1) { 
  printf("輸入分數(-1結束)：");
  scanf("%d", &score);
  count++; 
  sum =sum + score;
 } 
 printf("加總:%d  平均：%f\n",sum+1, (double) sum / count ); 
 return 0;
}
```

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int score = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int count = -1;
    while ( score > 0 || score <=100)
    {
        printf("輸入一個介於0~100的整數(-1結束)：");
        scanf("%d", &score);
        count++;
        sum = sum + score;
    if ( score == -1)
    {
        break;
    }
    }
    printf("加總： %d 平均： %f", sum+1, (double)sum / count);
    return 0;
}
```

I know I'm just learning from the beginning,
my teacher said that let's not think too much about the user could input score over 100 or less than -1,
But I just can't help to think about we should **first examine whether the input score is within 0~100**, if it is then proceed the program,
and then the program will keep asking the user to input more, until the user input -1 and print the result of sum and the average.

so that's why I choose to wrote
 `while ( x >= 0 || x <= 100)`
I can't figure out what is missing in the thought process.

Am I thinking the right direction?
How can I better fix the code?

Comment: `while ( score > 0 || score <=100)` This should be `&&`. Otherwise _any_ value will produce `true`.

Comment: Also, the code is written in [tag:C], not [tag:C#]. They are 2 very different languages.

Comment: Your teacher is trying to teach you how to use the while loop. In a real world program, you better check if the input is within 0~100, but in this example it's not needed. You'll probably do hundreds of examples like that one; if you try to, minutely, check all possible inputs, you'll take a long time with something you already know. You can do what you did (with the while condition updated as others have said), but you don't need to.

Comment: You must initialize score validly..

Answer (score 2):

I think you were on the right path, but you did miss something

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int score = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int count = -1;
    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf("輸入一個介於0~100的整數(-1結束)：");
        scanf("%d", &score);
        if ( score == -1 || score > 100 )
        {
            break;
        }
        count++;
        sum = sum + score;
    }
    printf("加總： %d 平均： %f", sum+1, (double)sum / count);
    return 0;
}
```

The important thing is to *immediately* exit the loop, without using the value of `score`, if it is not a valid score. Note that the `while` loop just runs indefinitely. It is only the `break` that stops looping. Also, note the logic in the `if` statement: we want to exit if the value is too low OR too high. This is the opposite of the way you'd written the code, because you wanted the loop to continue as long as the value was less than 100 AND more than -1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your while loop condition.

```
while (score > 0 && score <= 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is C code not C#

you can try this:

```
int main()
{
    int score;

    do {
        printf("Enter a number between 0 and 100: ");
        scanf("%d", & score);
    } while (score > 0 && score <=100);

    return 0;
}
```